# Is it possible for me to be a skinny man?

Tags: weight-loss, health

I am an 18 years old boy and I was about 98.5 kg a year ago. I was on a diet to lose weight, which I lost 32 kg by it, but now I am hoping to become skinnier. Should I keep this hope or it is impossible?

I feel that even when I am dieting my chest and upper back shape is not changing much, while on my waist I notice a good loss in fat. Why is my body not losing fat equally from its parts? How can I lose the fat in my chest and back? I also noticed that my biceps and triceps are much thinner than before while my forearm is not losing much.

I have attached some photos so that if someone may help me can see my body disorder shape, and I really hope someone help me to have a better body figure.

My body measurements are:

- Height 173 cm / weight 66 kg
- Chest 37 inch
- Shoulder 15 inch
- Sleeve length 23 inch
- Length 15.5
- Waist 31 inch
- Hip 35 inch

Comment: Your Google Drive is private unless otherwise specified, so we can't see them.

Comment: There is really no question that can be answered by the people on the site, as we can't just say "Yeah, you can be skinny". Also, you need to check some of your terms, "foramen" just means opening. Did you mean forearm there? If you have some specific questions we can probably answer those, but just "Can I be skinny" is going to be primarily the opinion of each person.

Comment: I updated the photos links , and corrected the word , sorry for that.  And to be specific , how can i lose fat in my chest and make it flatter ? And is that possible ??

Comment: Do you lift weights?

Comment: No, i do 3 rounds of pushups (15 each) daily , and 3 time a week sit ups (3 rounds 25 situp each round ) , i don't want my muscles to become big too much

Comment: Dude you're 18... You can definitely be leaner if you don't have any metabolic disease, just keep it up with eating a (mostly) healthy diet and exercise regularly. Make sure you 
 burn more calories than you eat, and don't give up! Don't forget to enjoy life in the proccess!

Comment: Thank you very much for encouraging me , i will always try my best